# Is it possible to get test status in JUnit from RunListener.testFinished?

Tags: java, junit

I need to process failed and passed tests differently in JUnit. But JUnit `RunListener` has only `testFinished()` that called whenever test failed or not, and `testFailed()` that is called only on failed tests.

Is there a way to find out test result (fail\pass) from `RunListener.testFinished()`?

Also, I was looking into another JUnit class -- `TestWatcher`. It has `succeeded()` method. But I don't want to use it because I also need to perform some actions when all tests are done ( `testRunFinished()` in `RunListener`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this with a RunListener class is to mark the failed tests with a child description in the testFailure() method and then check for that child description in testFinished() method:

```
class MyRunListener extends RunListener {
  private static final Description FAILED = Description.createTestDescription('failed', 'failed')

  @Override
  void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
    failure.description.addChild(FAILED)
  }

  @Override
  void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
    if (description.children.contains(FAILED))
      // Process failed tests here...
    else
      // Process passed tests here...
  }
}
```